# Customise Stacked Bar Data Labels

Tags: google-sheets, bar-chart, emoji

I have a dataset in google sheets that shows how often I do certain sports. I have created a stacked bar chart by month to follow the trend. I would like to use emojis to use as the data labels so that I don't need to have a legend. However I do not know how to change the data labels from being a count and to be customisable text?

For example for swimming I'd like it to show the emoji:  rather than "2" for jan, "4" for feb etc.

[image: sports]

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

**It's not possible for stacked charts**. It is for regular Charts, as you can see in this solution:

You can use emojis as labels by **adding notes to the chart**. You will have to copy the emojis from external sites and do the following [steps](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/9085344?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en):

> 1. In the column to the right of each data point, add your text notes (in this case, emojis).
>
>    [image]
> 2. Double-click the chart you want to add notes to.
> 3. At the right, click **Setup**.
> 4. In the box next to "X-axis," click **More** and then **Add labels**.
>      [image]
> 5. Enter the data range with your notes. For example, C1:C3.
>      [image]
> 6. Click OK.

In my case, the chart looks like this:

[image]

---

Since your Chart is stacked, this is not possible for this case. I recommend you to request this feature to Google by clicking on `Help > Send feedback`.